# Any way of avoiding this type inference problem?

Tags: f#, type-inference

If I have a function defined as

```
let test = function
    | [] -> None
    | head::tail -> Some(head)
```

fsi will allow me to define this and the compile will compile it; but it will fall over should I ever actually try to do `test []`.

Now I know the reasoning, when I give it an empty set it can't infer the type and so the generic function fails, but can it not do something a bit cleverer? (along the lines of, "I don't know the type of `'a` but in this case I'm not using `'a` so I'm going to allow this.")

Anyway, is there any way I can avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great [article about value restriction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN and [additional notes about tricky aspects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx) by Brian that explains this problem in details.

When you write `test []` the result has a type `option<'a>`, so the compiler needs to know the type to be used in place of `'a`. You're not actually using values of type `'a`, but the compiler needs to compile the code that uses it. F# doesn't allow working with *generic values* (in general) so the value needs to have concrete type.

You can write something like:

```
let foo () = test []
```

This is a standard generic *function* of type `unit -> option<'a>`, so this is a perfectly valid construct. You can also use type annotations to specify the type of the result explicitly:

```
(test []:option<obj>)
```

Comment: well, you can write let foo() = test [] - but foo will still error when you try to execute it... Where's the fun in that? Marking as answer because specifying obj looks like the only way around.

Comment: @Massif - The question is, how do you want to use the result and where does the input list come from? In any real example, you'll use the code in some context that will specify the type. (This is not the case with partial function application examples from Brian's article, but your code will probably appear in some wider context.)

Comment: either you got the wrong link, or the wrong name, or Brian's real name is Dmitry Lomov1 :)

Answer (score -1):

Surely putting the [] case last would do this?